# Joining two tables produces no result despite common values

Tags: mysql, date, join, many-to-many, union

My fiddle is [here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/mALNg1YXoWJhf1Wbdmhekz/17)

What I am trying to achieve?

I need to sum up income and sum up ad spend for each product in each month.
So the first query is summing ad cost for each product each month.
The second query is summing up income for each product during each month.
And the third query should merge this result and produce this table:

My first query looks like this:

```
SELECT ap.product, DATE_FORMAT(min(ai.date), '%m-%Y') as date, ROUND(SUM(ai.ad_spend)) as monthly_cost
FROM ad_insight ai
JOIN (SELECT ad_id, product FROM ads_products anp) ap ON ai.ad_id = ap.ad_id
GROUP BY ap.product, YEAR(ai.date), MONTH(ai.date)
ORDER BY min(ai.date) asc;
```

My second query looks like this:

```
select pi.name, round(sum(pi.value)) as monthly_income, DATE_FORMAT(min(pi.date), "%m-%Y") as date
from product_insight pi
where pi.name in (select distinct anp.product from ads_products anp)
group by pi.name, YEAR(pi.date), MONTH(pi.date)
order by min(pi.date) asc;
```

And now I want to join this queries, so I do something like this:

```
SELECT ap.product, DATE_FORMAT(min(ai.date), '%m-%Y') as date, ROUND(SUM(ai.ad_spend)) as monthly_cost
FROM ad_insight ai
JOIN (SELECT ad_id, product FROM ads_products anp) ap ON ai.ad_id = ap.ad_id
join (
  select pi.name, round(sum(pi.value)) as monthly_income, DATE_FORMAT(min(pi.date), "%m-%Y") as date
  from product_insight pi
  where pi.name in (select distinct anp.product from ads_products anp)
  group by pi.name, YEAR(pi.date), MONTH(pi.date)
) jpi on jpi.name = ap.product and jpi.date = ai.date
GROUP BY ap.product, YEAR(ai.date), MONTH(ai.date)
ORDER BY min(ai.date) asc;
```

But this joined query produces no rows. Why?

The final query should produce this table:

```
| product | date    | montly_cost | monthly_income |
|---------|---------|-------------|----------------|
| prod1   | 04-2021 | 11          | 38             |
| prod2   | 04-2021 | 17          | 16             |
```

Comment: A [mre] belongs in your post, not just at a link.

Comment: Debug questions require a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code including initialization; desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. For SQL include DDL & tabular initialization code. For debug that includes the least code you can give that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. [ask] [Help] When you get a result you don't expect, pause your overall goal, chop to the 1st subexpression with unexpected result & say what you expected & why, justified by documentation. (Debugging fundamental.)